# AngularJS custom filter called twice and delete input data on second call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here are the codes.

```
var app = angular.module("nameApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.controller("ctrlname", function ($scope, $http, $filter, apiKey, apiUrl) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.pageSize = 5;
});
```

The $scope.data will contain an array of data from an HTTP GET request.
The following is a code for a custom filter for the purpose of pagination of results. Basically, this will limit the results to only 5. Buttons for pagination will update $scope.currentPage's value.

```
app.filter("limitResults", function ($filter, $log) {
    return function (data, page, size) {
        if (angular.isArray(data) & angular.isNumber(page) && angular.isNumber(size)) {
            var startPage = (page - 1) * size;
            if (data.length < startPage) {
                return [];
            } else {
                $log.info(data);
                $log.info(page);
                $log.info(size);
                $log.info(startPage);
                return $filter("limitTo")(data.splice(startPage), size);
            }
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
});
```

This is the HTML page that will render the data.

```
<div class="row resultItems" ng-repeat="video in data.videos | limitResults:currentPage:pageSize">
    <div class="col-sm-3 testing">
        <img ng-src="{{video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url}}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 testing">
        <h5>
            {{video.snippet.title}}
        </h5>
        <p>
            {{video.snippet.channelTitle}}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{video.snippet.description}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I put a few lines of $log.info code in the custom filter in order to see what really happens when the filter is applied. The filter runs twice, which is a normal behaviour.

What I find confusing is that when the custom filter runs for the first time, $log.info(data) logs the original data received from a HTTP GET call to the console. However, when the custom filter runs for the second time, $log.info(data) logs an empty array to the console.

Given the fact that "$log.info(data); $log.info(page); $log.info(size);" get logged to the console, it is obvious that the second IF statement (if (data.length < startPage)) is evaluated to TRUE and the filter (return $filter("limitTo")(data.splice(startPage), size);) is applied.

I just don't understand why the array, which is the data passed to the custom filter, gets emptied when the filter runs the second time.

Comment: Try also logging `startPage` and `data.length` when you `return []` and see what happens.

Comment: I think you need to modify the filter expression. try `return $filter("limitTo")(data, size,startPage );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing empty array is because of the splice method.

```
$filter("limitTo")(data.splice(startPage), size);
```

**Splice method syntax**

```
array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])
```

If splice method is called without second parameter, that means if deleteCount is not passed, deleteCount will be treated as [arr.length - start]. In your case, when the first time filter executes, the entire array becomes empty.

[See this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for splice method